# É correto adotar uma especificação de design para um projeto inteiro?

Tags: gui, ux

Vejo muitos frameworks, migrando para um visual baseado em [material design](https://material.io/guidelines/)
e usando [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) para comportar os elementos, dentre elas.

- [Bootstrap](https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/)
- [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/)
- [Quasar](http://quasar-framework.org/)
- [Foundation](http://eucalyptuss.github.io/material-foundation/)
- [Material UI](http://www.material-ui.com)

Considerando que são componentes de UI, devem ser usados como complementação de algo já modelado não? um exemplo disso é o [jquery UI](https://jqueryui.com/).

Já vi sites de concessionárias usando, no qual o nicho são pessoa que ainda usam tecnologias incompatíveis com parte da estrutura desses frameworks.

Por fim gostaria de saber, se é correto adotar uma especifícação de design para um projeto inteiro?

Comment: Para o downvote e o fechamento, se puder explicar o motivo ficarei grato.

Comment: Na minha opinião o máximo possível já que o mesmo foi criado a partir de estudos que comprovam que aquele modo de fazer, para a maioria dos usuários, é o melhor

Comment: @vnbrs, tentei editar mais ao foco, mas não sei se adiantará alguma coisa, já vi várias perguntas do gênero sendo fechadas por serem 'baseadas em opiniões' ou pelo menos aparentam ser, cada vez mais ux está se tornando algo exato, baseado em estudos e técnicas, se nos limitarmos a opiniões, nunca sairemos do lugar, acho que até vale um debate no meta sobre isso.

Comment: Havia dois votos para reabrir a pergunta. Dei o meu voto de moderador para reabrir de uma vez e com convicção. Embora não seja designer, sei que UX não é uma ciência tão exata como programação, mas possui práticas que são consideradas corretas ou não, principalmente porque onde trabalho um padrão de UX tem sido fortemente adotado e é uma tendência em várias plataformas que conheço. Além disso, acho que a pergunta é muito boa porque ela não pergunta sobre "o melhor", mas sim se é "correto", o que não invalida outras abordagens, mas parte de um princípio prático.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seguir *guidelines* não é uma regra. São, como a palavra diz, orientações.

### Quem é o seu público-alvo?

Por que você seguiria os padrões de design do iOS para fazer um aplicativo Android? Os usuários do robozinho estão acostumados com o visual e a maneira de usar os apps. Assim funciona para o contrário.

Os usuário Windows estão acostumados com o Fluent Design, os do Google com o Material e da Apple com o Flat.

Criar um novo padrão de design é válido, mas tem que ser feita uma boa análise. De forma padrão e inteligente você quer deixar o seu usuário usar uma plataforma que ele já está acostumado e que ele já sabe usar. É mais custoso re-ensinar o público à utilizar sua aplicação.

### Recicle e reutilize.

Reutilizar um padrão já definido é sagaz. Seu usuário já está adequado ao estilo de utilização. O Material Design está presente em todos os produtos da Google. Se você usa o buscador, Gmail, YouTube, Maps ou Chrome, você conhece o Material Design. E assim também funciona com seu usuário.

### O camaleão.

Sua aplicação se adapta a cada ambiente. No Android você tem alguns padrões do Material, mas sem perder a sua forma, a essência do seu aplicativo. No iOS tenha sempre o menu na parte inferior da tela, é assim que se utiliza a grande maioria dos apps nesse sistema. <del>No Windows Phone... bem, eu não sei como é o WP.</del>

O [Uber tem seu próprio design, suas próprias guidelines](https://d1a3f4spazzrp4.cloudfront.net/uberex/Uber_API_Design_Guidelines_20160329.pdf) mas se adapta a cada sistema operativo. Isto é, no Android, iOS e Windows o visual muda, com algumas adaptações às orientações definidas por cada plataforma.

#### Não é só sobre a beleza.

Não seja tolo de achar que as guidelines de uma especificação contempla somente cores bonitas e animações interessantes.

[image]

Vou utilizar de exemplo o Material:

O botão de ação principal no canto inferior direito é padrão. O usuário exposto à esse design está habituado com esse funcionamento. Com os cards enfileirados lado-a-lado e a posição do botão voltar também.

Todos esses componentes são posicionados de maneira estratégica e houveram estudos do comportamento humano para serem postos de uma certa maneira. No I/O 2014 foi dito que o Material Design foi feito em base nas interações do mundo real.

- [Material Design guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/)

O Material não se prende ao Android e pode ser utilizado em aplicações web, assim como é feito em todos os produtos Google e mais sites externos.

- [Don't risk making a crappy UI, use Material Design](https://uxplanet.org/dont-risk-making-a-crappy-ui-use-material-design-520ebaceffe4)
- [Is it acceptable to use Google Material Design in web applications?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/109714/is-it-acceptable-to-use-google-material-design-in-web-applications)

#### O que é certo e o que é errado?

Em conclusão, não existem certos e errados. O padrão de design de interação deverá ser definido por você e sua equipe, existem diversas opções, dentre elas:

- usar o Material Design;
- usar o Material Design no ambiente Android e seguir as orientações da Apple no iOS;
- criar uma nova especificação que se adapte às diferentes arquiteturas (como o Uber);
- criar uma nova especificação que será padrão para qualquer ambiente (como a Google e o Material);
- mesclar especificações de design que já foram estudadas em termos de interação humano-máquina;
- entre diversas outras opções.

O **errado** talvez seja não utilizar um padrão. Seu projeto pode ganhar um padrão durante o desenvolvimento, esse é o caso mais comum. Entretanto, quando você já tem algo sólido, concreto, bem definido e documentado, o desenvolvimento flui melhor, mais fácil e mais rápido.

Answer (score 6):

## TL;DR

Em termos gerais, sim. E não só para um projeto, mas para a família inteira de projetos se possível.

## Exemplo prático

Vamos tomar como exemplo a recém lançada [*linguagem de design* da Atlassian (Atlassian Design Guidelines)](https://atlassian.design/).

> ***Aviso: trabalho na Atlassian, mas como desenvolvedor e não como designer.***

A empresa tem focado, especialmente no último ano, numa reestruturação profunda em termos de UI/UX, o que começou com a próprio marca (logos e tipografias) até a padronização dos componentes utilizados em seus diversos produtos com o [AtlasKit](https://atlaskit.atlassian.com/).

É importante salientar que tudo isto não é uma simples frescura, fetiche, uma decisão aleatória ou porque porque a empresa tem dinheiro sobrando.

Foram realizadas frequentes e variadas pesquisas, incluindo *feedback* de milhares de usuários ao redor do mundo e diversos outros dados estatísticos, e chegou-se à conclusão de que *oferecer uma experiência consistente (dentre outras características) nos seus diversos produtos é **essencial** para o negócio*.

Além de seus próprios produtos, oferecer o guia de *design* para o público em geral, permite que terceiros criem integrações e extensões para os produtos da Atlassian mantendo uma experiência consistente para os usuários. Todos ganham.

## "Frameworks visuais"

Obviamente, nem todas as empresas tem condições de investir em criar sua própria identidade, por isto tornam-se tão importantes como os "frameworks de design" citados na pergunta.

Faz todo sentido para um projeto que está começando especificar e adotar um padrão de design. Apenas seria importante ter um designer experiente para fazer isto de forma correta.

## Riscos

Um fator importante a se considerar é que adotar um padrão de UI/UX para guiar o desenvolvimento não pode se tornar um fator limitador.

Há alguns anos, trabalhei numa empresa onde foi desenvolvido um padrão de design porém sem possibilidade razoável de extender os componentes.

Isso obrigava os desenvolvedores a criar "gambiarras visuais" para os casos mais "diferentes", que na realidade eram justamente os mais complexos e importantes.

Portanto, é um erro pensar que, montada uma especificação de design usando algum framework, o trabalho acabou. Designers são necessários de forma contínua, sempre que um novo tipo de interação for identificado.

## Conclusão

Minha resposta, embora não deva ser interpretada como uma regra absoluta, é baseada em pesquisas, evidências e dados reais e objetivos dentro de um cenário comum a várias empresas, não sendo mero achismo ou filosofia arbitrariamente seguida.

Na prática, os questionamentos que persistem não são no sentido de se ter ou não um padrão de design - isto já é praticamente um consenso, mas da melhor forma possível de se fazer isto dentro do orçamento.

Comment: Essa semana recebi a documentação de uma API de um cliente feita por alguma ferramenta da Atlassian. Muito interessante! Não conhecia desde então.